# Can we weaponize RFID?

Tags: weapons

We have implanted RFID inside inmate body for tracking purposes, ID the pooches, etc. My question is in near future where all newborns are required by law to be tagged using RFID is it possible to use them as weapon to terminate the target remotely via radiowave signal or perhaps through WiFi? Disregard ethical and moral issues how can we prevent unauthorized hacking of these implants? It would be better if such device can deliver non-lethal but high electricity to incapacitate the target on command if it is viable. Also how to design it to be extremely difficult and tedious to be removed illegally?

Comment: Apart from the discussions from the comments below, RFID can't be used without some device closed to the intended target.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin that's is not exactly true.  To read the 'answer' you need to be relatively close, to set off the 'response' not so much.  Just need the right 'code' to ping the tag.

Comment: @bowlturner, I did not mean that you have to be in contact, but I couldn't from my sofa trigger yours. At least not without some form of relay...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin ah, true

Comment: Are you super attached to using RFID tags specifically? You could easily use some sort of microchip in the brain for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:
RFID tags are basically like a barcode that can be read with radio waves. They are an ID tag. That's literally the name: "radio frequency identification." RFID tags are already implanted in living things...particularly pets. The 'Microchip' that gets implanted in a pet, as a means of identification? Yeah...that is commonly an RFID tag. You can read information off of them, and (in some versions) write information to them. Something implanted in a person for identification purposes would be designed expressly to NOT be changeable, so that their ID couldn't be tampered with.

It's not like you have a computer in your arm or something, it's just an ID tag. And in the most likely case where the tags are read only, you can't even change the information stored on them because it is hardwired.

The way a modern RFID tag works is that when you hit it with a radio signal, it slightly modulates that signal in a way that represents the data stored on it. The reader detects these modulations, and interprets them. That's it.

Now, could you hit someone with enough energy to make the chip superheat and damage surrounding tissue? Sure! But that same amount of energy would probably harm the target directly, and that'd be a much more efficient use of resources.

EDIT: The only way this would work is if you had something else implanted. A bomb, an electrical weapon, whatever...and it was triggered by a specific transmission frequency to a logic circuit implanted in the skin that would trigger the device. But....you aren't weaponizing RFID...you are using RFID as a communication method, that could more efficiently be triggered by normal radio transmissions. Just to be clear, this system doesn't need to be anything advanced or large. It could be very simple...little more than a few transistors and a tiny battery

But, an RFID tag, by itself, cannot kill a person. It would need to be part of a system. And, in that case, there are more efficient ways of transmitting a kill-signal than RFID tags.

Comment: So there no room to squeeze in a small dose of cyanide and a valve?

Comment: RFID tags are passive. They don't do anything except echo back when called by a reader. They don't detect that they are being read, and then do something. The sum total of their life is this.
Wait.....
Reader calls for information
Deliver information
Wait......
That's it, they aren't computers, they just echo when called.

Comment: actually there are both active and passive RFID tags.

Comment: active just means it constantly transmits its data, powered by a battery. passive means it only transmits its data when asked (and powered by an ambient radio field). It doesn't imply that the RFID tag has the ability to process information given to it and do anything...it just stores it and transmits it. If you want something to do anything with data besides hold it, it must have a means of processing. RFID tags do not have such a thing. It's like plugging a flash drive into a monitor, with no computer attached, and expecting something to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The 1992 film *Fortress* has a similar idea. All inmates in this ultra-high-tech private prison are forced to ingest a device called an "intestinator" that is equal parts tracking device, pain-compliance tool and anti-escape measure. Various minor offenses trigger pain, such as crossing a yellow "warning" line within the prison or ticking off prison staff. Serious offenses such as crossing a red line or attacking a guard trigger the device to detonate with fatal effects.

Chemical explosives typically have a maximum density, but you could think up a variation of your RFID capsule implanted in the brain stem. Even a small explosive charge triggered by an encrypted radio signal would damage the stem, cutting off impulses for unconscious muscle actions such as breathing and heartbeat.

Comment: I'm so sorry that you actually suffered through that movie.  I feel your pain and I sympathize

Answer (score 0):

RFID tags are small.  Often many get their power from the 'reading' equipment.  So I see two small possibilities.  One, it holds a one time dose of a chemical that can kill/disable host.  The other is having it located very strategically so that a very small electric shock could trigger a crippling current.  This would likely be in the neck somewhere near the spine.  likely with a wire into the spinal column.

Comment:  I'm pleased to know this answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. In order for a toxin or electric shock to be administered, the RFID tag would need to do something with a signal it was given. RFID tags *are not capable* of that. If you designed it so that it went off when it got power, walking past a radio tower would be lethal. In order to take 'data' and do something with it, you have to have a processor. With RFID tags, you are basically taking a sheet of paper and writing 'kill someone' on it, then expecting it to do so. It doesn't have a clue what you just wrote on it, you just put information on it that someone else can read later.

Comment: They have the ability to be reprogrammed.  no reason for there not to be different circuits for different requests.  I'm pretty sure having two different 'responses' would be more than possible.  Granted it would need to be a bit more work, and maybe not be a true RFID tag but I'm betting it could work.

Comment: @guildsbounty Actually there are two types of RFID, passive and active. An active RFID has a battery and low power electronics, which could be used for either of the methods described here. However, the electric shock would almost certainly *not* cripple someone unless it was maintained, difficult to do with such a small energy source. The dose of poison is [entirely feasible](http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2015/implantable-drug-delivery-microchip-device-0629).

Comment: Except, again. They do not have a processor. They have NO IDEA what data is currently stored on them, or what the signals transmitted to them mean. If you add a processor in order to be able to interpret the data stored on them (and thus recognize the kill-code) then it isn't an RFID tag any more, it's a microcomputer.

Comment: @guildsbounty I think you're being a little intentionally obtuse. As some RFIDs have the ability to store data clearly they can perform actions depending on the signal given (read or write at minimum, I have an injectable RFID that reports body temperature too). They have a simple ASIC for this. Clearly if they can interpret the difference between a read and write request they can interpret the difference between a read ID and release toxin request. The logic required is dead simple.

Comment: @Samuel I'm certainly not trying to be. The question was specifically about RFID tags. The temperature sensing system you are talking about is a tiny computer system that uses RFID to communicate. And, as I said in my answer...if you install a microcomputer, then the idea works. But an RFID tag, by itself, is simply a data storage unit. A flash drive isn't going to kill someone because you told it to, unless you added some extra hardware to recognize the kill-command.

Comment: @guildsbounty Honestly the hardware is not as complex as you're making it out to be. It's an ASIC, not a microprocessor. There is a world of difference. If the RFID can store data then simple logic gates can AND some of the stored bytes with a predefined key. If the electrical output of that AND is a logical 1, then the kill switch can be activated. I see you're a software person, so you want to see all electronics in that way, but this requires no software. This is not a processor, it's a few dozen transistors.

Comment: @Samuel Sorry, that was poor phrasing on my part. You are completely right about the size and complexity of such a system. I shouldn't have used the terms 'processor' or 'microcomputer.' I am simply saying (as this is how I understood the question) that an RFID tag, *by itself,* is incapable of killing someone. I tweaked the answer I posted to make that a little more clear. If the question is edited by the asker such that it directly allows for RFID + a logic system, even if it is only a few transistors, then I will withdraw my answer.

Comment: @guildsbounty Fair enough. I suppose it's the difference between a gun killing someone and the bullet killing someone. The RFID is the gun, but a consumer off the shelf RFID isn't loaded.

Comment: Really I think the argument is that the asker said "RFID" but realistically I think he means "any implant which the public is told is an RFID". They put in a chip in you, said it's an RFID but actually it's something far more complicated. That makes it feasible. I would agree that a literal RFID makes it not feasible. Realistically, though, an attempt to implant something more complex would be discovered quickly by knowledgeable members of the public, very much like how trojan horses get found in apps: there are always white hat hackers looking for these things, mostly for fun.